# java irc bot disconnect after 11mints

Tags: java, irc

am trying to create a bot for my twitch channel it seem to be connecting ok and posting read/write fine
the problem is the app seem to die after 11 mints ever time 
any idea what i need to do to keep it connected forever?
(the " // We must respond to PINGs to avoid being disconnected."

i get no errors just BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 minutes 0 seconds)
seem to be working )

```
public class Twchatbot {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
    // TODO code application logic here
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long cur=System.currentTimeMillis();
    int i=0;
    String str[]={"XD","hi:)","cool"};   

    // The server to connect to and our details.
    String server = "irc.chat.twitch.tv";
    String nickname = "********";
    String password = "*******************";

    // The channel which the bot will join.
    String channel = "#********";

    // Connect directly to the IRC server.
    Socket socket = new Socket(server, 6667);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream( )));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream( )));

    // Log on to the server.
    writer.write("pass " + password + "\r\n");
    writer.write("nick " + nickname + "\r\n");

    writer.flush( );

    // Read lines from the server until it tells us we have connected.
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        if (line.indexOf("004") >= 0) {
            // We are now logged in.
            break;
        }
        else if (line.indexOf("433") >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Nickname is already in use.");
            return;
        }
    }

    // Join the channel.
    writer.write("JOIN " + channel + "\r\n");
    writer.flush( );

    // Keep reading lines from the server.

    while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {
        if (line.toLowerCase( ).startsWith("PING ")) {
            // We must respond to PINGs to avoid being disconnected.
            writer.write("PONG " + line.substring(5) + "\r\n");
            writer.write("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :I got pinged!\r\n");
            writer.flush( );


             if(System.currentTimeMillis()-cur>600000)  
             {
                 writer.write("PRIVMSG "+ channel +" :"+str[i]+"\r\n");
                 writer.flush();

                 i++;
                 if(i>=3)
                     i=0;
                 cur=System.currentTimeMillis();
             }

        }
        else {
            // Print the raw line received by the bot.

             if(System.currentTimeMillis()-cur>600000)  
             {
                 writer.write("PRIVMSG "+ channel +" :"+str[i]+"\r\n");
                 writer.flush();

                 i++;
                 if(i>=3)
                     i=0;
                 cur=System.currentTimeMillis();
             }
            if(line.contains("!enter"))
            {
                writer.write("PRIVMSG "+ channel +" :"+str[i]+"\r\n");
                writer.flush();
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
}
```

any tips will be welcome :)

 thx in advs

sry for the bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (line.toLowerCase( ).startsWith("PING ")) {
```

Think of what that does. It changes the line to *lowercase* and then checks if it starts with PING in *uppercase*.

Use the debugger and set breakpoints to see what happens and what doesn't. Errors like this become obvious.

Comment: i tryed to debug but netbeans didnt let me ;/  trying it out right now (it was posting the ping in the outpput line so was thinking it works